# Определение типа в обобщенном методе

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне нужен обобщенный метод, получающий коллекцию Control'ов из gridMain по критерию, переданному делегатом, опирающимся на их Tag (целое число). Задачу я решил вот так (все работает)

```
    private int GetTag<T>(T control) where T : Control
    {
        if (!(control is T)) return -1;
        int rez;
        return int.TryParse((control as T).Tag.ToString(), out rez) ? rez : -1;
    }

    private List<T> GetControls<T>(T type, TagCriteria cri) where T : Control
    {
        List<T> rezult = new List<T>();
        foreach (var control in gridMain.Children)
            if (control is T && cri(GetTag(control as T))) rezult.Add((T)control);
        return rezult;
    }
```

Но мне не нравится передавать параметр (например, null as ComboBox в строчке ниже) для определения типа.

```
 GetControls(null as ComboBox, x => x > 0).ForEach(x => x.IsEnabled = false);
```

Вопрос: Можно ли как-нибудь изящнее? Буду благодарен за комментарии к моему коду. Спасибо.

Comment: P.S. Обобщенным метод потому, что мне требуется получать Control'ы разного типа на разных участках алгоритма. Я понимаю, что метод должен откуда-то узнать, какой тип мне требуется в данном конкретном случае, поэтому вообще без параметра, скорее всего, не обойтись. Но [null as ComboBox] выглядит слишком уж костыльно. Поэтому и задаю свой вопрос.

Comment: Параметр `T type` не нужен, уберите его, тогда вызов будет выглядеть так: `GetControls<ComboBox>(x => x > 0)` А вообще вы делаете что-то очень странное, в WPF благодаря привязкам и шаблонам не нужна такая работа с контролами, лучше опишите свою реальную задачу.

Comment: И еще я не понял, зачем вы пишете `control is T` или `control as T` если у вас и так объявлено `T control`. Просто проверьте в самом начале один раз на `null` и всё, дальше будьте уверены, что у вас параметр правильного типа.

Comment: Убрать [T type] из параметров метода нельзя - т.к. делегат не содержит определения типа. Поэтому, если я убираю, как вы сказали, то вызов становится невозможным: "Аргументы типа для метода ... не могут определяться по использованию. Попробуйте явно определить аргументы".

Comment: Моя реальная задача - прямым образом управлять поведением контролов (IsEnabled, IsVisible и т.д.). Я знаю, что можно создать привязку этих свойств к bool'ам во ViewModel, но в данном случае это неудобно. Мне требуется динамически включать и делать видимыми контролы в зависимости от сложного алгоритма определения выбранного пункта в наборе других контролов. И просто завязаться на Tag оказалось реально удобнее, чем писать многоэтажные конвертеры, завязанные на значения других контролов. Но это не суть моего вопроса. Это костыль, но все мы иногда делаем костыли.

Comment: *Убрать [T type] из параметров метода нельзя - т.к. делегат не содержит определения типа.* – не понял, укажите тип в угловых скобках, как я показал

Comment: Спасибо! Не заметил сразу угловые скобки в вашем примере вызова. Вы ответили на мой вопрос. Так действительно изящнее!

Comment: Если я правильно всё понял, ваши пару методов можно переписать так: https://pastebin.com/Q2Vpj4VM

Comment: Ну и про конвертеры завязанные на другие контролы всё же я не понял. Ваша логика не должна находиться в представлении, пусть она будет в VM, а во View конвертеры будут простейшие типа BoolToVisibility

Comment: Мне кажется, это довольно расплывчато - что должно быть в представлении, а что - в модели. Для себя я решил так: в представлении вполне допускается логика поведения и изменения внешнего вида контролов, а любая логика обработки данных - только в модели. Мне кажется, это адекватное решение. И согласно ему, я делаю включение/отключение контролов в файле присоединенного кода представления. А обработка данных, разумеется, в модели.

Comment: Но вы мне очень помогли подсказкой и с синтаксисом вызова, и переписанными методами. Спасибо. На мой вопрос вы ответили полностью, даже более!